# cant hide div if value is empty

Tags: php, html, foreach

How to hide all data in that code? It hide only 'field_value' in foreach, but didnt hide all over information. Where is the problem? I need to hide all info in div if there is no 'field_value'.

When I have value in 'field_value', for exmpl '24', i see this:"abc 24 info", but when there is no value, i see this:"abc info". when value is empty i dont need to see anything. (field_value is from field_id, maybe i need to write if empty field value from that field id? how to do it?)

```
<?php
if(!empty($v['field_value'])) {
?>

    <div class="description"> abc

    <?php
    foreach($custom_fields as $v) {
        if($v['field_id'] == 22) echo $v['field_value'];
    }
    ?>

   <label>info</label>
   </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome! For us to be able to help you better, would you please provide a cleaner code sample? Also, you've mentioned a div in your subject, but you have not included a div in the code sample. We'll need to see that as well if we are going to help there.

Comment: Thnks, I have updated code.

Comment: When I have value in 'field_value', for exmpl '24', i see this:
abc 24 info, but when there is no value, i see this:
abc    info. But i need to hide all info, when there is no value

Comment: `$custom_fields` seems to be an array with field_id and field_values for **each** element. What should be the condition of the top? that all the different field_value are non empty? Some of them? If there is a field_value which is empty?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - what do you mean by "hide all info"? Should there be completely NO output if any of that `field_value` items is empty? So why not check for that before echo'ing?

Comment: any help? as answers before was not working

Answer (score 0):

According to the php [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for empty, a value is considered empty if it does not exist or it evaluates to false, check if this: $v['field_value'] is actually empty or not. 
You said that you want to hide all the data : "if there is no 'field_value'" then i suggest you check out [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)